# Removing count column from query output

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select top (5) t3.Model, t3.Manufacturer, t1.Colour, t1.RegistrationNumber, t1.DailyRentalPrice, count(t2.TruckID) as RentedAmount

from [IndividualTruck-PB] t1 

inner join [TruckRental-PB] t2 on t1.TruckID = t2.TruckID
inner join [TruckModel-PB] t3 on t1.TruckModelID = t3.ModelID

group by t3.Model, t3.Manufacturer, t1.Colour, t1.RegistrationNumber, t1.DailyRentalPrice

order by RentedAmount desc
```

Bsically, I'm trying to get the top 5 most rented but don't want the actual count column as output only as a means of ordering the output. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try remove the `count` column and give the formula to `order by` part:

```
select top (5) t3.Model, t3.Manufacturer, t1.Colour, t1.RegistrationNumber, t1.DailyRentalPrice

from [IndividualTruck-PB] t1 

inner join [TruckRental-PB] t2 on t1.TruckID = t2.TruckID
inner join [TruckModel-PB] t3 on t1.TruckModelID = t3.ModelID

group by t3.Model, t3.Manufacturer, t1.Colour, t1.RegistrationNumber, t1.DailyRentalPrice

order by count(t2.TruckID) desc
```

My test:

```
create table A (
  col1 varchar(255)
);

insert into A (col1) values ('A');
insert into A (col1) values ('A');
insert into A(col1) values ('A');
insert into A(col1) values ('A');
insert into A(col1) values ('A');
insert into A(col1) values ('A');
insert into A(col1) values ('A');
insert into A(col1) values ('B');
insert into A(col1) values ('B');
insert into A(col1) values ('B');
insert into A(col1) values ('B');
insert into A(col1) values ('B');
insert into A(col1) values ('B');
insert into A(col1) values ('C');
insert into A(col1) values ('C');
insert into A(col1) values ('C');
insert into A(col1) values ('C');
insert into A(col1) values ('C');
insert into A(col1) values ('D');
insert into A(col1) values ('D');
insert into A(col1) values ('D');
insert into A(col1) values ('D');
insert into A(col1) values ('D');
insert into A(col1) values ('E');
insert into A(col1) values ('E');
insert into A(col1) values ('E');
```

[Select](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) for MS SQL Server 2017:

```
select top(2) col1 from A group by col1 order by count(col1) desc;
```

Output:

| col1 |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

Comment: select does work in MySQL 5.6 (and later), but `TOP` is unknown, in MySQL you have to use [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html)  BTW: this is also mentioned on the site you refer.